# listener that groups jms messages then sends to next queue / batching messages

Tags: grails, jms

I need to implement a listener that receives multiple messages then groups them base on a certain criteria then send the grouped messages to the next queue. In other words batching them in a logical way.

I'm using Grails and JMS integration plugin.

In my mind, it can be implemented in a listener that runs a single thread that runs an infinite loop that forever consume messages from a queue then do the grouping logic there.

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      while(true) {
         def obj = consumer.receive()
         //group the messages and store on a list then send them in groups to the next queue
         producer.send(groupedObjList)
      }
   }
}
def thread = new Thread(runnable);
thread.start();
```

I'm not sure if this is a clean way to do it. So I'm looking for alternatives on how to implement this.

Comment: What is the criteria for grouping ? Is that information present in the original message ?

Comment: @ramp Yes, its in the original message

Comment: You could add them as headers to the original message and use message selectors on your receiver which will ensure that the receiver receives only one kind of messages. You would need a receiver per message criteria.

Comment: @ramp The goal of grouping was to have less number of messages and processing them in batches. So if I use a selector, it will just have a control on which listener will consume it but will still be processed one by one.

Comment: You are going to group the messages into a single one logically? Messages are always processed one by one afaik, at least in JMS.  I am not sure if there is a way to consume messages in batch.

Comment: @ramp Yes, thats is right, into a single one logically. Yeah, right now, I can only think of just looping on the jms consumer. Hoping someone have a better solution.